# How to search and edit only 'date type' cells in an excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code

```
Sub fill()
  Dim rg As Range
  Set rg = Range("a1")
  Set rg = Range(rg, Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, rg.Column))
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rg Is Nothing Then
    rg.Value = "1/1/2020"
  End If
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work as I wanted to.

I need to search in a whole excel worksheet range(a1:bj1223) and check all 'date type' cells. when it finds a cell that is 'date type' and it is empty, i need to add the value "1/1/2020" in this cell.

thank you

Comment: i mean the cells that are define as Format(Date, "Short Date")

Comment: Ok use the code code that I gave below and check. How is short date displaying on your pc? "mm/d/yyyy" or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? This will first look for blank cells and then check if each cell in that range is of a specific format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` Change that as applicable.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim blnkCells As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BJ1223")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set blnkCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not blnkCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In blnkCells
            If aCell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" Then aCell.Value = "1/1/2020"
        Next aCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you use instead fo "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: i use "dd/mm/yyyy" but it doesn't fill any cell

Comment: It cannot be :) If it is filling those cells then that means that those cells were formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy". To check. Click on the cell and then in the Immediate window (in VBE) type this "?Activecell.NumberFormat"